# Chrome default_popup not running Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add this to my default_popup on Chrome, however, it seems the javascript does not run, at all. I've tested it on JSFiddle and as an isolated file, and it works fine. However, once adding it to my extension, it does not work.

Edit: Updated the code to fit what I thought would work according to the first answer. However, it does not work.

popup.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
          // Some CSS used in the page 
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
        <div id="save">Do Stuff</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(e) {
  window.alert("asdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) in Chrome extensions and apps. You're not allowed to use inline scripting.

Comment: How would I do it then, as <script> blocks aren't allowed, so I can't reference a local script?

Comment: You can reference a local script.js.  You can't include the script in your html.

Comment: I updated the OP with the new code I have, which does not work.

Comment: Try making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).  Your html file only needs 8 lines.  Or you can write off Stackoverflow for not being willing to put more work into your problem than you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to test if your script is executing successfully or not then do something like this

#### JS (script.js)

```
alert('Script is running');
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(e) {
  window.alert("asdf");
}
```

Secondly, there is a problem in your code. You are trying to bind an event listener on `save` element which does not exist in DOM when you are attaching the event. So

- load your script in the end (OR)
- Attach event listener when document is ready

So to fix your problem, just try loading script in the end. Change the order of `div#save` and `script` tags to look something like this

```
<div id="save">Do Stuff</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Let me know if it does not solve your problem.